# Caroufredsel Pagination: Not numbers but Titles

Tags: javascript, pagination, carousel, caroufredsel

I am creating a carousel pagination using Caroufredsel plugin. I want to create custom unique Titles rather than the default numbers in the pagination. I want each Title to be totally different. At the moment I managed to use "anchorBuild" to add in aplphabetical Titles (e.g. test) but not completely different Titles. Your help will be appreciated!

```
    $('#foo0').carouFredSel({
      auto: { duration: 600 },
      pagination: {
        container:".menu",
        anchorBuilder: function(nr) { return '<li><a href="#"><span>Test '+nr+'</span></a></li>';}
      },
      mousewheel: true,
      swipe: { onMouse: true },
    });
```

```
<ul class="menu">
  <li><a href="#environment">Environment</a></li>
  <li><a href="#market">Marketplace</a></li>
  <li><a href="#community">Community</a></li>
  <li><a href="#workplace">Workplace</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [plugin's documentation](http://docs.dev7studios.com/category/11-caroufredsel) (older docs are found [here](https://dev7studios.com/caroufredsel-old/configuration.php)) you can simply set `achorBuilder: false` and then use your own HTML markup with custom titles.

So something like this for your HTML (note: I added `<span>`s to match the docs):

```
<ul class="menu">
  <li><a href="#Environment"><span>Environment</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="#Marketplace"><span>Marketplace</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="#Community"><span>Community</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="#Workplace"><span>Workplace</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

And then your jQuery:

```
$('#carousel').carouFredSel({
    auto: {
        duration: 600
    },
    pagination: {
        container: ".menu",
        anchorBuilder: false
    },
    mousewheel: true,
    swipe: {
        onMouse: true
    }
});
```

Here is a working **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7F8Ka/1/)**.

Comment: Documentation is gone. Can't find info about parameters in the official page

Comment: @AlwinKesler Thanks for the heads up, looks like they have been moved to http://docs.dev7studios.com/category/11-caroufredsel with more at https://dev7studios.com/caroufredsel-old/configuration.php

Comment: Thank you. The second link has was I was looking for